# Spring Jsps and Jumping to Anchors

Tags: spring, jsp, anchor

I was wondering if there is some way in Spring to specify in the controller that I would like to send the client to a specific anchor within the .jsp page that I am using for my view.

I have a section in my .jsp page, identified by an `#errors` anchor, that displays any form errors that occur. I would like to be able to send them directly to that anchor whenever I need to send them back to the .jsp after model validation fails.

Inside my controller classes, I handle validation errors like so:

```
if (result.hasErrors())
        {

            for (ObjectError error : result.getAllErrors())
            {

                logger.debug("Validation Error: " + error.getDefaultMessage());
            }

            ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();

            mv.setViewName("/secure/formViews/newAdminBookingMenu");
            mv.addObject(BindingResult.MODEL_KEY_PREFIX + "booking", result);

            return mv;
        }
```

I would like to be able to specify in that code block that when the client gets the rendered `newAdminBookingMenu.jsp` back that they are sent directly to the `#errors` anchor tag within that page.

I obviously cannot do this by just adding `#errors` to the name of the .jsp i wish to render as the InternalResourceViewResolver will interpret the view as `/WEB-INF/jsp/jspName#errors.jsp` which is clearly incorrect.

I know this can be accomplished with javascript and the `onload` event but I find that kind of dirty and would really rather find a Spring approach if one exists.

Any ideas?

Cheers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps a `RedirectView` is an option:

```
modelAndView.setView(new RedirectView("error/page#errors", true));
```

**Reference:**

- [15.5.3.1 RedirectView](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-redirecting-redirect-view)

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer? I can't see the connection between the .jsp page of the example with the string you put in RedirectView