# Can I return ModelAndView with parameters?

Tags: model-view-controller, spring, parameters, modelandview

I must return address `myaccount.htm#box-two` with `modelMap`.
`"#box-two"` is very important for me, when I put:

```
return new ModelAndView("redirect:myaccount.htm#box-two", modelMap);
```

it doesn't work, I got my parameters in my URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/RestFinderWebApp/mojekonto.htm?nameError=Name+required#box-two
```

I tried also:

```
return new ModelAndView("myaccount#box-two", modelMap);
```

but it failed.

Answer (score 0):

A `RedirectView` will be your friend, as pointed out in this post: [Spring Jsps and Jumping to Anchors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170472/spring-jsps-and-jumping-to-anchors)