# Spring MVC controller returning a page with an anchor (#)

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, spring-mvc, anchor

I am quite surprised I have to make this question because I expected other people would have encountered the same as me. Maybe I didn't put in the right keywords in the search engine, or maybe I have no idea what I am doing. :P

Anyways,
I have a Spring view resolver bean which appends '.jsp' to a String returned from a method which gets a request. What I would like to do is add an anchor to the String so I can scroll to a certain element in the page, if I do it now I get page not found error.. can anyone give me some advice how to do this?

Thanks in advance!
Davey

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring Jsps and Jumping to Anchors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170472/spring-jsps-and-jumping-to-anchors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I have done is, put my (needed) modelAttributes in the sessionAttribute (Thanks @Boris Treukhov) and sent a redirect to another controller with an anchor (e.g. site/edit#123). In this method I get the data out the Session and put it in the model, then Returning the page.

Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 2):

you need to add an onload script in the jsp which will navigate to anchor tag

```
   <script>
     location.href=controllerurl#tag
   </script>
```

Comment: No I mean, how can I return a view with an Anchor inside the controller? Was that not clear from the question?

Comment: yes it was, I think you cant do it from within the controller.

Comment: @Davey Spring MVC uses view resolver to forward to jsp pages, if you want to change the address of the web page you should use redirect instead. So you must return something like redirect:newurlwithanchor instead of the view name in your controller.

Comment: @BorisTreukhov thanks for your comment, it's really useful and I tried it, but with a redirect I lose what's inside my model and it is quite essential for me that does not happen.. :/ do you have any other ideas perhaps?

Comment: @Davey you can store the data in the session, but I don't know the specific use case - imho it's already too complicated when you have a spring controller in the middle of the processing, it looks like rather an html question about anchors to me(maybe you should just use internal html anchors? Then *this* answer is correct.). Again, the use case is not clear.

Comment: Yeah I've chosen to do specific modifications and such in the controller, because I don't want to do everything with jQuery and such. So the controller is more complicated than you would expect I guess. I don't know what internal html anchors are though, and I don't know if I clarified your doubts with this small explanation